# Proper Subsets of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Every non-empty proper subset of Real Numbers is either open or closed. true/false

Comment: Hi! Welcome to math.stackexchange. Note that although we are a question and answer site, it is considered polite to phrase your question as a request rather than simply stating the problem verbatim. It would also be useful for members trying to help you to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here are some familiar subsets of $\Bbb R$: $[0,1]$, $(0,1)$, $[0,1)$, $\Bbb Q$. Can you tell me which of them are open? Closed?

Comment: i m sorry, about the way i posted my question. i will keep in mind the next time
 for the questions:
[0,1] closed
(0,1)open
[0,1) left-closed and right-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is false.**

> For example, $[0,1)$ is not open, since $0 \in [0,1)$ has not a nbhd $U$ such that $0 \in U\subset [0,1)$. Also, $[0,1)$ is not closed, since the point 1 is accumulation of $[0,1)$, however 1 is not in $[0,1)$.